# Delete all records in all tables that have a unique record

Tags: sql-server

Am working on `Microsoft SQL server`

I have a database with 30 `tables`

Some tables have a column called `LicenceID`

I want to Force delete all records in all the tables that have `LicenceID = 38` 
When i mean force delete, i want to delete even if there is `constraints`

Please can anyone help me
Thx
mike

Comment: If you want to delete them regardless of constraints, why do you have constraints in the first place? A constraint is pointless if you aren't going to enforce it.

Comment: In fact, thinking further on the subject, if your constraints and foreign keys are set up correctly, you could use a "simple" cascade delete. Then you could delete your row in the licences table (what ever the root table is) and the deletes would cascade and delete any other rows.

Comment: and why do you want to do that, exactly? Even if you achieve it, you'll just leave a broken data structure in place afterwards, waiting for more errors to occur. Better to delete the data which is related as well, so it's all consistent afterwards. As Larnu says, that's the whole point of relational integrity. And yeah, cascade delete might be your friend.

Comment: Maybe you can set the values in the other table to NULL? Also something you could be doing with your constraints.

Comment: well am not who designed the db unfortunately and i never used CASCADE delete before. Can anyone pinpoint me the correct T-sql syntax. thx

Comment: If it's not implemented already, @humer2000 then you'll need to change every relevant constraint to implement it; even with a small amount of tables (like the 30 you have) that will take a little time to implement correctly. You can't alter a constraint after it's created, so you'll need to `DROP` them and then re`CREATE` them. Likely you'll want to script **all** of your foreign key constraints out (your Source Control tool will be really useful for this, you *do* have one right?) and then add the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option to them.

Comment: The documentation covers how to `CREATE` a constraint on an existing object as well: [Create a foreign key in an existing table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017#create-a-foreign-key-in-an-existing-table)

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to determine table dependencies (if is dependent of another table or there are tables that are dependent from the initial table; in base of that (and if you can't alter the constraints for some reason), deactivate temporally its constraints (for each table):

```
ALTER TABLE <NAMETABLE> NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

do the necessary deletes in each table which is dependent and then reactivate its constraints (again, for each table)

```
ALTER TABLE <NAMETABLE> CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Try this with `ROLLBACK` first

PD: I think maybe there are better solutions, but I hope it helps

Comment: And suddenly all of your constraints are untrusted. https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/foreign-key-trusted/

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are there for a reason. Spend the time, figure out the dependencies, and do the deletes in the right order so that you don't violate them.

Comment: the fact is that the db was built by a another developper who wrote for a windows application. Today the boss charged me to build a web application in the cloud and replace the old win app. so i built the website with non longer need of the constraints created for the app as i did it withing the code.